# Dynamically programming style in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have created a piece of code that is meant to dynamically create a linearLayout and populate it with textViews at the push of a button - AND apply a style.

quickTest is the name of the style I am trying to apply.

TableManners is a layout in which I am trying to force this whole ordeal.

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
        val linearshell = LinearLayout(this, null, R.style.quickTest)
        linearshell.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        linearshell.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        linearshell.textAlignment = LinearLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER

        val Name = TextView(this)
        val CurrentPlace = TextView(this)
        val Date = TextView(this)

        Name.text = "WowwoW"
        CurrentPlace.text = "Here"
        Date.text = "11/04/2020"

        TableManners.addView(linearshell)
        linearshell.addView(Name)
        linearshell.addView(CurrentPlace)
        linearshell.addView(Date)

    }
```

The style in question:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="quickTest">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/Redmen</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundstyle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The roadblock I am facing is the style is not applying.

Comment: I don't think the third argument in the `LinearLayout` constructor if for `style resource id`.

Comment: OhhhThatVarun, I do believe you are correct. Now my question to you is, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
        val themeContext = ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.quickTest)
        val linearshell = LinearLayout(themeContext, null, 0)
        linearshell.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        linearshell.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        linearshell.textAlignment = LinearLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER

        val Name = TextView(this)
        val CurrentPlace = TextView(this)
        val Date = TextView(this)

        Name.text = "WowwoW"
        CurrentPlace.text = "Here"
        Date.text = "11/04/2020"

        TableManners.addView(linearshell)
        linearshell.addView(Name)
        linearshell.addView(CurrentPlace)
        linearshell.addView(Date)

    }
```